# How to convert a sequence of Task<MyType> to a sequence of MyType

Tags: f#, task, saturn-framework

So I currently have a sequence of type `seq<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Restaurant>>` and I want to turn it into a sequence of type `seq<Restaurant>`.

I'm currently using TaskBuilder.fs library and from my research, I need to use either let! or do! for this situation but they require `task {}` which when used with Seq.map bring back the same Task type.

```ml
let joinWithReviews (r : Restaurant) =
    task {
        let! reviewResult = Reviews.Database.getByLocationId cnf.connectionString r.Restaurant_Id
        match reviewResult with
        | Ok reviewResult ->
            let restaurant = { r with Reviews = (List.ofSeq reviewResult)}
            return restaurant
        | Error ex ->
            return raise ex
    }

let indexAction (ctx : HttpContext) =
    task {
        let (cnf:Config) = Controller.getConfig ctx
        let! result = Restaurants.Database.getAll cnf.connectionString
        match result with
        | Ok result ->
            let restaurantWithReviews = (Seq.map joinWithReviews result)
            return index ctx (List.ofSeq restaurantWithReviews)
        | Error ex ->
            return raise ex
    }
```

So my result is of type `Seq<Restaurant>` and I need to add reviews to each restaurant so I use Seq.map to get restaurantWithReviews which is type `seq<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Restaurant>>` which I won't be able to use.

Comment: Are you trying to do some of the processing in parallel or not?

Comment: I don't need to process it in parallel but my database calls are of type Task and the framework I am using required the same of my IndexAction.

Comment: To turn a `seq<Task<TResult>>` into a `seq<TResult>`, the easiest way would be a simple `|> Seq.map (fun task -> task.Result)`. The [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result) say that accessing the `Result` property of a Task will block the thread until the result is available, and do note that this would be sequential, not parallel. But it's definitely the easiest and simplest way to do what you need.

Comment: Thank! That is enough to serve my needs.

Comment: What if i want to run `Seq.map` sequentially without having to block the thread with calling `task.Result`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET method `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll` will convert `seq<Task<'a>>` to `Task<'a[]>`. You can get the result with `let!` if you're inside a `task { }` block.

```
let restaurants: seq<Restaurant>

let! withReviews: Restaurant[] =
    restaurants
    |> Seq.map joinWithReviews
    |> Task.WhenAll
```

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick. The type are a bit off bit it is easy enough to switch between them.

Comment: This saved me so much today, thank you!

Comment: Note that this solution will return an eagerly evaluated array. If you want to maintain the `seq` behavior, FSharpPlus has a function `SeqT.run` that can maintain the sequence-like behavior while evaluating the tasks. I.e., evaluating the first 2 items, will not start the tasks of the next items.